# MVC4 Devexpress Sorting, Grouping and Filtering not working

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I am working on devexpress and having some problems. Here is my code:

```
settings.Columns.Add(column =>
{
    column.Caption = "Code";
    column.Settings.AllowGroup = DefaultBoolean.True;
    column.SetDataItemTemplateContent(c =>
    {
        ViewContext.Writer.Write(DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "Code"));
    });

    column.SetEditItemTemplateContent(c =>
    {
        if (DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "Code") != null)
        {
            ViewContext.Writer.Write(DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "Code"));
        }
        else
        {
            Html.DevExpress().TextBox(textBox =>
            {
                textBox.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
                textBox.Name = "Code";
            }).Render();
        }
    });
});
```

im adding a column like this and it is showing right values, bu sorting or grouping or filtering is not working. How can i make those functions work?
Please Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `FieldName` of the column, which is the name of the column or property in the DataSource to which the Grid is bound:

```
column.FieldName = "Code";
```

That allows the control to know which field will filter and sort. Also, you may need to allow sorting and filtering:

```
column.Settings.AllowSort = DefaultBoolean.True;  // I think this is the default
column.Settings.AllowHeaderFilter = DefaultBoolean.True;
```

If you need to define other filtering options, you can also set the `HeaderFilterFillItems` method at the grid settings, and modify the `Values` collection at the event args parameter:

```
gridSettings.HeaderFilterFillItems = (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName.Equals("Code")) {
        e.Values.Clear();
        e.AddValue("DisplayOption", "Value", "Query");
        // ...
    }
};
```

**UPDATE**: If your column has custom data, then it is unbound, and you can use the event `CustomColumnUnboundData` to define the value of the column, which will also be used to filter/sort the grid:

```
// Same column definition as yours
settings.Columns.Add(column =>
{
    column.Caption = "Code";
    column.Settings.AllowGroup = DefaultBoolean.True;
    column.SetDataItemTemplateContent(c =>
    {
    ViewContext.Writer.Write(DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "Code"));
    });

    column.SetEditItemTemplateContent(c =>
    {
        if (DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "Code") != null)
        {
            ViewContext.Writer.Write(DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "Code"));
        }
        else
        {
            Html.DevExpress().TextBox(textBox =>
            {
                textBox.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
                textBox.Name = "Code";
            }).Render();
        }
    });
});

// CustomUnboundColumnData event handler
settings.CustomUnboundColumnData = (sender, e) => {
    if(e.Column.Caption.Equals("Code")) {
        // You can get the value of any existing field in the datasource, this way:
        string code= (string)e.GetListSourceFieldValue("Code");
        // Do some processs to get the custom value
        // ...
        // And set it to the Value propery of the event args parameter
        e.Value = myCustomValue;
    }
};
```

You can find an example of unboud data in this link: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E2824

Comment: i didn't understand what you mean by asynchronous callbacks. My problem is when i add SetDataItemTemplateContent or SetEditItemTemplateContent to any column, sorting or grouping or filtering isn't working. I think i need custom implementation but i couldn't do that.

Comment: I see, sorry, I didn't understand. I had the same issue yesterday. I will update my answer.

Comment: @user2702694, I have updated my answer. Try, and let me know if it worked :)

Comment: i tried your solution but not worked. i don't use field value so i didn't initialize column.FieldName . my field is custom.

Comment: thank you very very much man :) you solved my greatest problem :D i can do many thing on column now i didn't know to unbounding would solve :D I'm very grateful to you @Guillermo Gutiérrez

Comment: You are welcome, @WeyCell :) Glad to hear it helped.